# Argument "n-1" of subroutine call gives a syntax error

Tags: recursion, abap, towers-of-hanoi

I want to program a Tower of Hanoi solver in ABAP.

Here's my current code:

```
FORM SOLVE USING s1 TYPE c
             s2 TYPE c
             s3 TYPE c
             n  TYPE i.

  IF n = 1.

    "move disc from tower X to tower Y"
    WRITE:/ text-001, text-002, s1, text-003, text-002, s3.

  ELSE.

    PERFORM solve USING s1 s3 s2 n-1. "Here's my problem, n-1 doesn't work"

    PERFORM solve USING s1 s2 s3 1.

    PERFORM solve USING s2 s1 s3 n-1.

  ENDIF.

ENDFORM.
```

**My problem:**

If I chose an `USING` parameter like `n-1`, SAP recognizes it as a (not existing) structure and throws an error to me.

Is there a way to accomplish this anyway?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need add space between operator. So you need to type as `n - 1`. On the other hand old version ABAP not support in-line operand as function/perform parameter. If you get error, firstly assign result to new variable then pass it as parameter.

Comment: To add to this, "n-1" is interpreted as, "the *1* field on the structure *n*". As mkysoft answered, adding the spaces changes this to the subtraction operation.

Comment: As you say expressions are not supported for arguments after [PERFORM](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abapperform_parameters.htm) whatever the version is but [subroutines are obsolete](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abensubroutine_glosry.htm) so [methods](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenmethod_glosry.htm) should be used, where [expressions are supported](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_static_short.htm).

Comment: If I assign n - 1 first to variable and pass it as parameter, the algorithm doesn't work correctly. For this recursive solution I need to pass n - 1 as param anyway.. but I'll try again

Comment: I'll try it with classes and methods. I will post the result here as fast as I can

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It works pretty well. Thank your all for your useful tips.

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZS_SANDBOX_TOH
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& 
*& Datum: 19.09.2018
*& Beschreibung: Lösungsprogramm für das Türme von Hanoi - Problem
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT ZS_SANDBOX_TOH.

PARAMETERS: p_discs TYPE i.

CLASS myclass DEFINITION.

  PUBLIC SECTION.

    CLASS-METHODS solve IMPORTING s1 TYPE c
                                  s2 TYPE c
                                  s3 TYPE c
                                  n1 TYPE i.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS myclass IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD solve.

  IF n1 = 1.

    WRITE:/ 'Lege Scheibe von Turm ', s1, ' auf Turm ', s3.

  ELSE.

    solve( s1 = s1
           s2 = s3
           s3 = s2
           n1 = n1 - 1 ).

    solve( s1 = s1
           s2 = s2
           s3 = s3
           n1 = 1 ).

    solve( s1 = s2
           s2 = s1
           s3 = s3
           n1 = n1 - 1 ).

  ENDIF.

ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

CALL METHOD myclass=>solve( s1 = 'A'
                            s2 = 'B'
                            s3 = 'C'
                            n1 = p_discs ).
```